# /entrypoint.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: django, windows, docker-compose

Docker project was created on Linux machine, I'm running windows and I can't get `docker-compose up` to work. I've read through Stackoverflow's answers and so far I've tried the following (none have worked):

- Using Visual Studio Code I saved as "LF" instead of CRLF
- Deleted the file entirely, created a new one using Visual Studio Code, typed the words
- Cut the entire file, pasted it in Notepad so that formatting gets cleared, copied and pasted back
- Added various forms of `#!/bin/bash` to the start of the `entrypoint.sh`
- Changed Docker File to use COPY instead of ADD

At this point I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

**Edit**

*entrypoint.sh*

```
if [ "$1" == 'celery' ]; then
  celery -A vicmun worker -l info --uid=celery --gid=celery
else
  ./../wait_for_it.sh db:5433 --timeout=10
  python manage.py migrate
  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
fi
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ARG APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
RUN mkdir /src
RUN mkdir /static
WORKDIR /src
ADD ./src /src
ADD entrypoint-${APP_ENV}.sh /entrypoint.sh
ADD wait_for_it.sh /wait_for_it.sh
RUN addgroup --system celery && adduser --system --ingroup celery celery
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/wait_for_it.sh"]
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ffmpeg
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, what's on line 8 of entrypoint.sh?

Comment: A new line character (tried both \n and \r\n)

Comment: The file you show doesn't have 8 lines?  Often the error means a quotation mark or `fi` directive is missing, but that isn't obviously the case in the file you've included.  How are you running the container; is the script built into the image actually being run, or are you replacing it with something else when you run the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Looks like I can't get the code to highlight the last character that I'm pasting into the text box, so I've added a print screen of the file.  I'm running the container through "docker-compose up" command. "is the script built into the image actually being run" no, the up fails, no contianer ever goes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel the cringe for this. Turns out the solution was something I had already done, but it didn't go through until I rebuilt with **--no-cache** option.

Solution was to:

- Using Visual Studio Code I saved as "LF" instead of CRLF
- and run `docker-compose build --no-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your config, but I could resolve that problem by adding in the CMD.

In my case, I could execute a script with docker as follows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.15
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN  apk update \
  && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
  && pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .

CMD [ "sh", "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Same error continues to show after I implemented the changes suggsted (using CMD, using shell, and adding shell comment on entrypoint)

Comment: The error was on me for not rebuilding with --no-cache option. Thank you!